# How to implement 'one-time-code' in interval function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a function - checker - on front-end which works every 10 seconds.

```
async check() {
  this.globalLoader = true
  const result = await finalizePayment({
    id: this.id ? this.id : undefined,
    paymentId: this.paymentId ? this.paymentId : undefined,
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  })
  this.globalLoader = false
```

This function returns transaction status, and if it's done, I implement my Google Analytics code:

```
  if (result.status === 'done') {
      ...
  }
```

But there is a problem, I need to implement this GA code **only one time**, when transaction is done. If user reloads page, this `check()` function will return `result.status === 'done'` and my GA code will run again, but I don't need that again, because I have already made GA record about transaction.

So, how can I make it? I was thinking about `localStorage` value, but what if user removes this value from local storage?

Comment: if the user removes it from localStorage then no other way but to store the value in the db. But in reality an end user won't remove the values from sessionStorage

Comment: If he is gonna do so, then it means he wants to intentionally `reset` things so do GA

Comment: Hence I insist you to use `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to localStorage then I suggest you to go with `vue-persist`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist